# ASP.NET MVC 4: Issue on URL after deploying the project. (IIS 7)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I've this piece of code and it is working on my local copy but when I publish it in IIS 7, it is not working anymore.
The problem occurred in the URL which is "url: "/dashboard/GetEvents_v2""...
I think, it is not going on that location because it is always failed...
Please advise.
.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var events = [];
        var selectedEvent = null;

        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();

        function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
        alert('FetchEventAndRenderCalendar');

            events = [];
        alert('ajax');

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",

                url: "/dashboard/GetEvents_v2",

                success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('failedzzz');
                }
```

.[directory link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNpnV.png)
Same thing happened on my image, it is not showing on the webpage.
I have an image on below directory, but it is not showing...
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wms\Images\Avatar\avatar.jpg
See image directory, it is present there.
Note too, that it is working on my local copy but not in published IIS.

.
Here's the log: Error on "**GetEvents_v2**" and "**/Images/Avatar/avatar.jpg**". Please help!

```
#Date: 2018-05-24 02:55:26
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2018-05-24 02:55:26 ::1 GET /wms/Dashboard - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 500 0 64 5077
2018-05-24 02:55:28 ::1 GET /wms/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 200 0 0 1382
2018-05-24 02:55:28 ::1 GET /wms/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 404 3 50 2
2018-05-24 02:55:28 ::1 GET /wms/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 404 3 50 0
2018-05-24 02:55:29 ::1 POST /wms/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 302 0 0 36
2018-05-24 02:55:29 ::1 GET /wms/Dashboard - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 200 0 0 448
2018-05-24 02:55:29 ::1 GET /Images/Avatar/avatar.jpg - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 404 0 2 0
2018-05-24 02:55:29 ::1 GET /wms/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 404 3 50 25
2018-05-24 02:55:29 ::1 GET /dashboard/GetEvents_v2 - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 404 0 2 37
2018-05-24 02:55:29 ::1 GET /wms/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 404 3 50 8
```

Comment: what means when you say is not working? Which error you get 404, 500? Did you tried to reach the deployed service on IIS calling the url directly in the browser? eg: `http://localhost/dashboard/GetEvents_v2`

Comment: it is not working means it is alerting "failed"... because I guess no data retrieved and did not go to the controller to retrieve the data...

Comment: @Jadina what just try to google chrome and press F12 and inspect the element path. what exact path is there for the image.

Comment: here's the path when I inspect the element in google chrome "<img class="uk-comment-avatar uk-border-circle" src="/Images/Avatar/avatar.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="">"  same in my local copy... but not working when i publish in IIS

Comment: How did you publish it? The site and its back end web service must both be registered upon IIS, or such 404 is expected.

Comment: Sir, I publish the project via visual studio... right click the project then publish and my target location is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wms...
I can connect to the database now problem here, it's not dislaying what i am expecting to see.... I just want that what I see in my local copy must be the same in my testing.